# Is there a fisheye or dual fisheye to equirectangular filter for ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, fisheye, 360-degrees, theta360

Or a way to do it with an existing filter?  So that you could take in video from a fisheye or dual fisheye camera (such as the Ricoh Theta) and directly output equirectangular, in real-time, to something like RTMP?

Comment: Was you able to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes see the accepted answer below, it works!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Remap](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter) filter does just this:

> This filter copies pixel by pixel a source frame to a target frame. It
>   remaps the pixels to a new x,y destination based on two files
>   ymap/xmap.

Basic command syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i fisheye_grid_input.jpg -i fisheye_grid_xmap.pgm -i fisheye_grid_ymap.pgm -filter_complex remap out.png
```

Also included at that link are the [mapping files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/wiki/RemapFilter/ThetaS_remap_files.zip) for

> Ricoh Theta S camera: input files for resolution 1920x960(1080)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Do you know where can I find PGM files for Ricoh Theta S 1280x720 resolution?

Comment: Is there a way to do this for an existing video? instead of just an image?

Comment: Sure. Replace first input with video. Insert `-loop 1` before 2nd and 3rd inputs. And output to video.

Comment: @gumis I've extended the `projection` tool so you can generate projection files for dual-fisheye cameras too, you can get it at https://github.com/raboof/dualfisheye2equirectangular

Comment: How can I tune the maps to make them compatible with different FOVs? My camera has 235° FOV, others have 220 or 190 or 180.  A FOV >180 is mandatory to have a good stitching, but SW must take into account the overlapping.

Comment: Excelent, but do you know how to apply the remap filter over a camera output instead of a single image?

Comment: Use a video as the first input. If the filter doesn't reuse the X/Ymap images, add `-loop 1` before each of the image inputs.

Comment: It worked with videos and webcam streams but, when I try to get this work with ffserver and a webcam, I have the following error "MPEG 1/2 does not support 15/1 fps". I dont know how to make it work

Comment: Add `-r 30` to change output to 30 fps.

Answer (score 10):

In the latest ffmpeg, you can do this to convert fisheye video to equirectangular now

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -vf v360=dfisheye:e:yaw=-90 -c:v libx265 -b:v 40000k -bufsize 5000k -preset ultrafast -c:a copy out.mp4
```

- y : overwrite output without wanring
- i xxx : input file
- vf yyy: use filter

  - yyy: filter parameters
  - v360 : filter name

    - dfisheye : double fisheye (rectangular image containing two spheres/fisheye); use "fisheye" to use single sphere/fisheye
    - e : abbreviation for "equirectangular"
    - yaw : view direction  (=azimut) of center of equirectangular output (=look left/right); use "pitch" to look up/down
    - ih_fov : input horizontal Field Of View; half sphere is 180°, but some cameras arrive to 235°
    - iv_fov : input vertical Field Of View, usually identical to ih_fov
    - h_fov : output horizontal FOV
    - v_fov : output vertical FOV

Docs: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360

Note: filter works fine both with image or video as input

Comment: some comments to the parameters would be useful; I only know the ones for images...