# FFMPEG Remap with video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to use FFMPEG Remap filter to convert a circular fisheye video to an equirectangular shape. In doing so, I am using the projection script as documented in the Remap page of the FFMPEG docs to generate the map files for my camera.

**My issue is this:** 
I am successful with processing still images, but when attempting to output video, I only get black frames.

*Original*
[image: Original Image]

*Converted*
[image: Converted Image]

Based on this link:
[Is there a fisheye or dual fisheye to equirectangular filter for ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796911/is-there-a-fisheye-or-dual-fisheye-to-equirectangular-filter-for-ffmpeg)
I believe I need to use the -loop argument before my filter files in order to process the image data as a frame, however when I attempt this, I get an error:

```
    failed to reallocate parser buffer
```

### My question is:

Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly use FFMPEG remap on a video file?

Here is the current command I'm using (does not work unless i remove -loop argument)

```
    ffmpeg -i short.mp4 -loop 1 -i xfly.pgm -loop 1 -i yfly.pgm -filter_complex remap -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

### [EDIT] Updates

After additional research, the -loop option should come *before* file input, not the image map input... like so

```
    FFMPEG -loop 1 -i file.mp4 -i x.pgm -i y.pgm -filter_complex remap out.mp4
```

However now I get:

```
    Option loop not found
```

-loop appears to only be supported by certain image extensions

Comment: Can you share the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i x.pgm -i y.pgm -filter_complex remap,format=yuv444p,format=yuv420p out.mp4
```

The remap filter only outputs fully sampled chroma and not [subsampled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) formats, and most players only play 4:2:0 subsampled video, so a format filter has to be inserted to convert to an acceptable format.

The issue here has nothing to do with looping the video or the maps. The remap will reuse static unlooped maps for all frames of the video.

Comment: This accomplished the primary conversion, however outputs in grayscale. 

Related?
[remap filter gives only black and white output](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2017-November/037964.html)

Comment: spot on! --- I will continue to research YUV format to understand exactly what's going on with the cmd you provided

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of FFMPEG now implement V360 filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360:fisheye:equirectangular:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=0 -y output.jpg
```

- -i input file
- -vf video filter

  - v360: VR360 panorama conversion

    - fisheye: source format
    - equirectangular: destination format
    - ih_fov: input horizontal FOV
    - iv_fov: input verticalFOV
    - pitch: camera up/down orientation
- -y Overwrite
- Output file

Probably it is not very precise because it is "universal", but at least it is easy to use.